# The following assertion was thrown building ItemCard(dirty): setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I'm new to flutter, and I'm trying to build an Online Shopping app as my graduation project.

Every time I run the app it goes straight the "Item Card" method and through it to "Details Screen", even though it's supposed to only go there on pressing through the Navigator widget.

It's also marking the Item Card as a dirty child (I don't quite understand what that means and how to revert it to being a normal child).

```
   Error message: The following assertion was thrown building ItemCard(dirty):
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

I hope I explained the error well enough.. here is the code,
First is the Body class, then Item Card class, and then Details Screen class:

```
    class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kDefaultPaddin),
          child: Text(
            "Mobiles",
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .headline5!
                .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
        Categories(),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kDefaultPaddin),
            child: GridView.builder(
                itemCount: productz.length,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  mainAxisSpacing: kDefaultPaddin,
                  crossAxisSpacing: kDefaultPaddin,
                  childAspectRatio: 0.75,
                ),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => ItemCard(
                      productz: productz[index],
                      press: () => Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => DetailsScreen(
                              productz: productz[index],
                            ),
                          )),
                    )),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ItemCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Productz productz;
  final Function press;
  const ItemCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.productz,
    required this.press,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: press(),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(kDefaultPaddin),

              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white12,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
              ),
              child: Hero(
                tag: "${productz.id}",
                child: Image.asset(productz.item_image),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: kDefaultPaddin / 4),
            child: Text(
              // products is out demo list
              productz.item_name,
              style: TextStyle(color: kTextLightColor),
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            "\$${productz.item_price}",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Productz productz;

  const DetailsScreen({Key? key, required this.productz}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // each product have a color
      backgroundColor: Colors.white12,
      appBar: buildAppBar(context),
      body: Body(productz: productz),
    );
  }

  AppBar buildAppBar(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white12,
      elevation: 0,
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back,
          size: 30,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.search),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.shoppingCart),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        SizedBox(width: kDefaultPaddin / 2)
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onPress` function in the `GestureDetector` is being invoked immediately.

There are two ways you can go about fixing the problem.

1. Remove the call to the function, by removing the `()`
2. Wrap the press function in an anonymous function, so that I can be invoked later when the user actually performs the action, this is usually done when you need to evaluate a variable, For Example in the `onChanged` handler of `TextField` or `TextFormField`

Check the code snippets below.

*Example of Method 1.*

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: press,
      child: ...
   )
}
```

*Example of Method 2:*

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => press(),
      child: ...
   )
}
```

Comment: This should work too , I added a Future Delayed instance

Comment: @Rohan
I've tried your first solution, it's showing this error message: "The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'."

Comment: @HassanWaqqaf second solution or my answer should work

Comment: @Rohan would you mind adding this to your answer : "Previously , `press()` passes the result to `onTap`, but we require a `function (closure)` to be passed to `onTap`, that when executed, calls `press()`"

Comment: @HassanWaqqaf Yes, just update your `ItemCard` class variable to match the type, that is make `press` be of type `'void Function()?'`

Comment: @HassanWaqqaf No Problem :), Remember if this answer helped you , consider marking it as the accepted answer, so we can help others on the StackOverflow Community with the same question.

Comment: @RohanThacker Hey Rohan, I'm sorry if this seems out of order but there are a few stuff I need some advices about in my flutter project, is there any way we can communicate if you have the time?

Comment: @HassanWaqqaf My twitter and github is in my profile, add me there we can discuss. No issues

Comment: @RohanThacker I made an account on github but couldn't find a chat button to start one, also github is saying that some features are restricted for me because I'm Syrian, same goes for twitter, can't create an account without verifying it with a phone number, and Syria isn't even listed there, so.. is there any other way we can communicate.. ?

Comment: okay that sucks, sorry to hear that...give me your email here and I'll tell you when i take it after that you can delete it

Comment: got it..i sent you an email

Answer (score 0):

Deferreing it to the next tick will work -

**Previous**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: press();
      child: ...
   )
}
```

**Change to :**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
             press();
             }),
      child: ...
   )
}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, this error message came up: "The argument type 'Future<Null>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'."

Comment: @HassanWaqqaf what exactly did you try?

Comment: this one: "onTap: Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
             press();
             }),"

Comment: @HassanWaqqaf can you try using `await` before press(); in my code

Comment: @anirudh the error message remains.. this null safety thing is getting on my nerves..

Comment: @HassanWaqqa Did you update the ItemCard class variable to match the type, add the ? after Function. That is `final Function press;` to `final Function? press;`

Comment: @HassanWaqqaf This source of you problem and your question has nothing to do with null-safety btw, you've made a small mistake and your answer is above. All the best

Comment: @anirudh Rohan's second solution worked! Thank you for your time as well!

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem...

remove the `()`

---

Going from:

`onTap: press(),`

to this

`onTap: press,`